# Delete first instance of matching element from array

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say I have the array `[1,2,3,1,2,3]` and I want to delete the first instance of (say) `2` from the array giving `[1,3,1,2,3]`. What's the easiest way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
li.delete_at(li.index(n) || li.length)
```

`li[li.length]` is out of range, so the `|| li.length` handles the case where `n` isn't in the list.

```
irb(main):001:0> li = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> li.delete_at(li.index(2) || li.length)
=> 2
irb(main):003:0> li.delete_at(li.index(42) || li.length)
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> li
=> [1, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. I've been beating my head trying to express this elegantly.

Comment: I don't understand the `|| li.length` can anyone please explain

Comment: Any value in ruby can be treated as a boolean value, with only `false` and `nil` evaluating to false. The double pipe syntax is a convenient shorthand. `a || b` means "a, unless it's nil, then b".

Comment: @erich2k8 so is `li.length` just another way of saying "don't delete anything (since length(n) is always beyond the array, and return 'nil'?"

Comment: @stevec Yes, exactly. This might be a bit confusing if encountered in the wild, but it's a way to make it a 1-liner that only does one traversal. Alternatively, you could store the index in a variable, then do the `delete_at` only if the variable value is non `nil`. Such variables are kind of just clutter after the check though. E.g. `index = arr.index(3) && arr.delete_at(index)` leaves that `index` variable around afterwards.

Comment: @erich2k8 ah, thanks for explaining. I see the rationale now. I must admit, I had no idea what it did when first reading it. I really like [@TNT's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32992979/5783745) to make it part of stdlib

Answer (score 15):

If `|| li.length` is to avoid sending `nil` to `li.delete_at` (which would result in a TypeError), then a more readable version might look like this

`li.delete_at li.index(42) unless li.index(42).nil?`

Comment: You probably want to store `li.index(42)` in a variable, to prevent doing the search twice. The performance will be much better for large arrays.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it should become part of stdlib:

```
class Array
  def delete_first item
    delete_at(index(item) || length)
  end
end
```

Comment: Strongly agree. `delete_at(index(item) || length)` is super easy when you know it, but not obvious otherwise. `delete_first` is very nice.

Comment: Is there a place to (more formally) make suggestions for ruby?