# In Ruby, is there a way to remove only 1 match in an Array easily?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, the array subtraction or `reject`

```
>> [1,3,5,7,7] - [7]
=> [1, 3, 5]

>> [1,3,5,7,7].reject{|i| i == 7}
=> [1, 3, 5]
```

will remove all entries in the array.  Is there an easy to remove just 1 occurrence?

Comment: This is very close to ["Delete first instance of matching element from array"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595305/delete-first-instance-of-matching-element-from-array).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
>> a = [1,3,5,7,7]

>> a.slice!(a.index(7))
=> 7

>> a
=> [1,3,5,7]
```

Comment: One may want to check that '7' actually exist, otherwise it may raise a type error.

Answer (score 15):

The best I can think of is:

```
found = false
[1,3,5,7,7].reject{|i| found = true if !found && i == 7}
```

Or destructively:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7]
arr.delete_at( arr.index(7))
arr #=> [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]
```

Comment: similarly: arr.slice(arr.index(7)) or arr.slice!(arr.index(7))

Comment: @andynu: The former doesn't do anything. One `slice!` works for this (because it happens to do the same thing as `delete_at` when called with one argument).

Comment: By the way, in second solution you also may need to add `if pos`, because `delete_at(nil)` throws exeption.

Answer (score -5):

While it doesn't directly answer your question, `uniq` might be what you want.

```
[1,3,5,7,7].uniq # => [1,3,5,7]
```

Comment: This is a bit aggressive. [1,1,1,1,2,2].uniq # => [1,2] removing considerably more than a single seven.

Comment: it removes all other duplicate elements as well, that's not what OP wants.

Comment: Well I did say it didn't answer the question :) That's what I get for trying to guess what the OP is *really* trying to do...