# Ruby difference in array including duplicates

Tags: ruby

`[1,2,3,3] - [1,2,3]` produces the empty array `[]`. Is it possible to retain duplicates so it returns `[3]`?

Comment: `Array#-` is a *set difference* operator. There is no standard method for this, but yes "it is possible".

Comment: I don't think you can do this using some built-in array method. But you can always write your own.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731553/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-to-remove-only-1-match-in-an-array-easily useful in the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am so glad you asked. I would like to see such a method added to the class `Array` in some future version of Ruby, as I have found many uses for it:

```
class Array
  def difference(other)
    h = other.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e,h| h[e] += 1 }
    reject { |e| h[e] > 0 && h[e] -= 1 }
  end
end
```

A description of the method and links to some of its applications are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987054/how-to-select-unique-elements).

By way of example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,4,2]
b = [2,3,4,4,4]

a - b          #=> [1]
a.difference b #=> [1,2,3,2]
```

Ruby v2.7 gave us the method [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), allowing us to replace the first line of the method with

```
h = other.tally
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this with a built-in operation. Can't see anything in the [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) either. Simplest way to do this would be to extend the array class like this:

```
class Array
    def difference(array2)
        final_array = []
        self.each do |item|
            if array2.include?(item)
                array2.delete_at(array2.find_index(item))
            else
                final_array << item
            end
        end
    end
end
```

For all I know there's a more efficient way to do this, also

Comment: You need to add `final_array` after your antepenultimate `end`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
As suggested by [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) in question comments, using [Array#slice!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) is a much more elegant solution

```
def arr_sub(a,b)
    a = a.dup #if you want to preserve the original array
    b.each {|del| a.slice!(a.index(del)) if a.include?(del) }
    return a
end
```

[Credit:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731553/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-to-remove-only-1-match-in-an-array-easily)

My original answer

```
def arr_sub(a,b)
    b = b.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){ |v,h| h[v] += 1 }

    a = a.each_with_object([]) do |v, arr| 
        arr << v if b[v] < 1
        b[v] -= 1
    end
end

arr_sub([1,2,3,3],[1,2,3]) # a => [3]
arr_sub([1,2,3,3,4,4,4],[1,2,3,4,4]) # => [3, 4]
arr_sub([4,4,4,5,5,5,5],[4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6]) # => [4]
```

Comment: Except you are now mutating `a`, so you should operate on `a.dup`.

Comment: I didn't catch that bug. I made your suggested changes to now operate on `a.dup`. Thank you @CarySwoveland