# How to scan and remove elements from an array and return the array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to scan an array of email addresses and remove particular domain addresses from the array, then return it.

This is my code:

```
matches = ["abuse@peterstar.net", "hostmaster@peterstar.net", "noc@peterstar.net", "noc@tristatevoicedata.com", "abuse@ripe.net", "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"]
email = Array.new()
emails = Array.new()
matches.each do |email|
  if email != 'nobody@peterstar.com' && !email.match('@peterstar.net') && !email.match('@ripe.net') && !email.match('@arin.net') && !email.match('@lacnic.net') && !email.match('@afrinic.net')
    emails = email
    puts emails
  end
end
puts emails
```

This is the script's output:

```
dpereira@affiliatedtech.com
```

I need to how to return an array with the given elements removed.  The above script returns only the last element of the array as string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034678/ruby-how-can-i-delete-one-element-from-an-array-by-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Regexp`:

```
re = /(^nobody@peterstar.com|@peterstar.net|@ripe.net|@arin.net|@lacnic.net|@afrinic.net)/
matches.select {| email | email !~ re }
# => ["noc@tristatevoicedata.com", "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"]
```

With array of emails, and email templates:

```
res = [
  'nobody@peterstar.com',
  /@peterstar.net/,
  /@ripe.net/,
  /@arin.net/,
  /@lacnic.net/,
  /@afrinic.net/, ]
emails = matches.reject {| email | res.any? {| re | re === email } }
# => ["noc@tristatevoicedata.com", "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"]
emails.last
# => "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"
```

Or use a convolution or reduction:

```
res = [
  'nobody@peterstar.com',
  /@peterstar.net/,
  /@ripe.net/,
  /@arin.net/,
  /@lacnic.net/,
  /@afrinic.net/, ]
  matches.reduce(nil) {| email, match | !res.any? {| re | re === match } && match || email }
  # => "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"
```

Please also refer to ruby [documentation on Arrays](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html), and stay away of PHP's manner of thought.

Comment: itworks thanks but i am unable to access email variable outside the loop :(

Comment: @user3155632 what do you mean in your context? to access variable outside of loop, you need to declare it before the loop.

Comment: yes of course i did like `email = ""` and even tried `email = nil`

Comment: it just gives `true` instead of outputting values

Comment: I exactly understood not that do you mean?

Comment: It seems somewhere in loop the variable has evaluated into `true`

Comment: here is my [fullscript](https://gist.github.com/itsbalamurali/8231517) this how i used your answer.

Comment: ok got it thanks :) finally solved.

Comment: @user3155632 I see, that is property ruby's irb to output return value as an echo: you shell just use `emails = matches.select... `, then `emails.last` or `emails.join(',')`, etc

Answer (score 0):

This pattern:

```
/(?:@(?:a(?:frinic|rin)|peterstar|lacnic|ripe)\.net|nobody@peterstar\.com)/i
```

matches your list in:

```
if email != 'nobody@peterstar.com' && !email.match('@peterstar.net') && !email.match('@ripe.net') && !email.match('@arin.net') && !email.match('@lacnic.net') && !email.match('@afrinic.net')
```

Here's how [Rubular displays it](http://rubular.com/r/CJGRALC4a7).

And here's how to use it:

```
MATCHES = %w[
  abuse@peterstar.net
  hostmaster@peterstar.net
  noc@peterstar.net
  noc@tristatevoicedata.com
  abuse@ripe.net
  dpereira@affiliatedtech.com
]
REGEX = /(?:@(?:a(?:frinic|rin)|peterstar|lacnic|ripe)\.net|nobody@peterstar\.com)/i
```

If you want strings that do *NOT* match:

```
MATCHES.reject{ |s| s[REGEX] }
# => ["noc@tristatevoicedata.com", "dpereira@affiliatedtech.com"]
```

If you want strings that *DO* match:

```
MATCHES.select{ |s| s[REGEX] }
# => ["abuse@peterstar.net",
#     "hostmaster@peterstar.net",
#     "noc@peterstar.net",
#     "abuse@ripe.net"]
```

The pattern uses the `i` flag to enforce case-insensitivity, which is important when dealing with email addresses, since they aren't case sensitive.