# What's an easier way to break down this array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of two values in a random order.
I want to find what the other value is and turn it into a string.

This is what I currently have in Ruby, but I'm trying to clean it up and make it more concise.

```
 array = ["garden_shop","some_value"]
 tag = array.delete("garden_shop")
 @tag = tag.first
```

Which should result in:

```
@tag = "some_value"
```

Comment: if you say `array.delete` than check the value of `array` it will have been modified. However if you use `-` or `find` as some answers suggest, you will get a new array as a result and the original will not be modified.

Comment: @maxple: The example in the [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43480555/1) left the structure unmodified

Comment: @user000001 it had `delete` still.

Comment: @maxple: True, I should have said that it left `event_payload` unmodified. I read the `tag_load` variable as temporary. Your first comment pointing out the difference is still useful though, in case OP (or anyone else) doesn't see the difference.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages. Your question isn't clear. Please reread it, and imagine a coworker handed you a sheet of paper with your question printed on it and then walked away. Could you answer the question? What would you want to know? It's important that all information needed to answer be in the question. When you clarify the question because of a comment then put the information into the question by modifying it and adding the info where you would have put it initially. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags as we can see what changed.

Comment: For instance "... and turn it into a string."? Your values are already strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-` operator:

```
@tag = (array - ["garden_shop"]).first
```

Source: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D
Related: [How can I delete one element from an array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034678/how-can-i-delete-one-element-from-an-array-by-value)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `find` is exactly you want:

```
array.find {|v| v != 'garden_shop'}
#=> "some_value"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
if array.first == 'garden_shop' 
  array.last 
else
  array.first 
end
# => "some_value"
```

This can also be written more concisely as:

```
array.first == 'garden_shop' ? array.last : array.first
# => "some_value"
```

but it sacrifices readability.

This might help:

```
array = ["garden_shop","some_value"]
compare do
  user000001 { (array - ["garden_shop"]).first }
  ilya { array.find {|v| v != 'garden_shop'} }
  ttm {
    if array.first == 'garden_shop' 
      array.last 
    else
      array.first 
    end
  }
end

# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> ttm is faster than ilya by 5x ± 1.0
# >> ilya is similar to user000001
```

And, just for thoroughness:

```
compare do
  ttm1 { array.first == 'garden_shop' ? array.last : array.first }
  ttm2 {
    if array.first == 'garden_shop' 
      array.last 
    else
      array.first 
    end
  }
end
# >> Running each test 32768 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> ttm1 is similar to ttm2
```