# binary alphabet sort ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, binary

i tried writing my own alphabet search for [Chris Pine tutorial chapter 7](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=07), and i waned to implement a binary method. there is no validity for string input, so i don't know what will happen with integers mixed with strings, but the idea was to do it for a list of strings only.

```
#get list of strings
puts "type words to make a list. type 'exit' to leave program."
x = ()
list = []
while x.to_s.upcase != 'EXIT'
    x = gets.chomp
    list.push(x)
end 
list.pop

#binary method

nano = list.length
half= list.each_slice(nano/2).to_a
left = half[0]
right = half[1]

nanol=left.length
nanor=right.length

#initialize results array

A = []

for i in 0..nano-1
    smallest_left = left.min
    smallest_right = right.min

        #no difference with this commented out or not
    #if nanol==0
    #    A<<smallest_right
    #end
    #if nanor==0
    #    A<<smallest_left
    #end

        #error message points to the line below (rb:44)
    if smallest_left<smallest_right
        A << smallest_left
        print A
        left.pop[i]
    elsif smallest_left>smallest_right
        A << smallest_right
        print A
        right.pop[i]
    else
        print A
    end
end
```

for input = ['z','b','r','a'] i can see the list being sorted in the error:

```
["a"]["a", "b"]["a", "b", "r"] rb:44:in `<': comparison of String with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

please help me see my error :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a lot of code that isn't idiomatic Ruby there. I'd strongly recommend taking a copy of the code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com once you figure out what's wrong here, and let them help you write it in a more Ruby-like way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is occurring because you are trying to compare nil. You get a different exception when nil is on the left.

```
'1' < nil
#=> scratch.rb:1:in `<': comparison of String with nil failed (ArgumentError)

nil > '1'
scratch.rb:1:in `<main>': undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Your code gets into this situation when the `left` or `right` array is empty (ie all of its elements have been added to A already). Presumably, this is why you had originally added the if-statements for `nanol == 0` and `nanor == 0` (ie to handle when one of the arrays is empty).

Your if-statements have a couple of issues:

1. You do need the `nanol == 0` and `nanor == 0` statements
2. The three if-statements are always run, even though only one would apply in an iteration
3. `nanol` and `nanor` are never re-calculated (ie they will never get to zero)
4. When the left and right values are equal, you don't actually add anything to the `A` array

The inside of your iteration should be:

```
smallest_left = left.min
smallest_right = right.min

nanol=left.length
nanor=right.length  

if nanol == 0   #Handles left no longer having values
    A << right.delete_at(right.index(smallest_right) || right.length)
elsif nanor == 0    #Handles right no longer having values
    A << left.delete_at(left.index(smallest_left) || left.length)
elsif smallest_left < smallest_right
    A << left.delete_at(left.index(smallest_left) || left.length)
elsif smallest_left > smallest_right
    A << right.delete_at(right.index(smallest_right) || right.length)
else #They are equal so take one
    A << left.delete_at(left.index(smallest_left) || left.length)
end
```

You will still have an issue (no error, but unexpected results) when your list has an odd number of elements. But hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: this was great! Thank you :) after all i get `'pop': can't convert Array into Integer (TypeError)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error. But looking at the code again, Array#pop was not the right way to remove the element from the array (as it removes the last element not the min element). I updated the code to use Array#delete_at (as discussed in this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595305/delete-first-instance-of-matching-element-from-array)).