# Get the exact differences of two arrays

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
array1 = [1,2,2,4,5,6]
array2 = [2,1]
```

How do I get

```
array3 = [2,4,5,6]
```

I have tried `array1 - array2`, but it returns `[4,5,6]`.

Answer (score 5):

What you are describing is a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). There is no implementation in the standard library, but you can use the [multiset gem](https://github.com/maraigue/multiset).

```
require 'multiset'

ms1 = Multiset.new([1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6])
ms2 = Multiset.new([2, 1])

ms1 - ms2
#=> #<Multiset:#1 2, #1 4, #1 5, #1 6>

(ms1 - ms2).to_a
#=> [2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find each element's [`index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-index) and delete that one, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595353/477037):

```
array1 = [1,2,2,4,5,6]
array2 = [2,1]

array2.each { |obj| array1.delete_at(array1.index(obj) || array1.length) }

array1 #=> [2, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: i am new to ruby. What does  "|| length" do in that statement?

Comment: `a || b` returns `b` if `a` is falsey, i.e. `nil` or `false`. In the code above, `array1.index(obj)` returns `nil` if `obj` is not found in `array1`. And since `array1.delete_at(nil)` would result in an error, `array1.delete_at(array1.length)` is used as a fallback.