# Synchronizing two arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am comparing arrays for the purpose of synchronizing. With the

```
arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f']
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I can't figure out how to synchronize these arrays. I have to figure out what elements would need to be added to one array while keeping in mind that duplicates are allowed. I need the distinct elements in `arr1` but not in `arr2`:

```
['a', 'a', 'f']
```

or the distinct elements in `arr2` but not in `arr1`:

```
['b', 'd']
```

Unfortunately, that isn't the way the `-` function works with arrays:

```
arr1 - arr2 # =>  ['f']
arr2 - arr1 # =>  ['d']
```

Comment: `'c,'`. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yep, thanks @SagarPandya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here an implementation of [TNT's elegant solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595305/delete-first-instance-of-matching-element-from-array/5768245) for deleting the first matching element of an array

```
class Array
  def delete_first item
    delete_at(index(item) || length)
  end
  def distinct other, own = self.dup
    other.each{|e| own.delete_first(e)}
    own
  end
end

arr1.distinct arr2 # ["a", "a", "f"]
arr2.distinct arr1 # ["b", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty!

```
def array_compare(arr1, arr2)
  arr2 = arr2.clone
  add_to = []
  arr1.each do |el|
    if index = arr2.index(el)
      arr2.delete_at(index)
    else
      add_to << el
    end
  end
  return add_to
end

-> arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c,', 'f']
["a", "a", "a", "b", "c,", "f"]

-> arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c,', 'd']
["a", "b", "b", "c,", "d"]

-> array_compare(arr1, arr2)
["a", "a", "f"]

-> array_compare(arr2, arr1)
["b", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

1. Count all occurrences in each array, and store in 2 hashes
2. Iterate through hash 1 and compare each count to hash 2
3. Output an array item for each additional count in hash 1
4. Flatten and output

Implementation:

```
h1 = arr1.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, e| total[e] += 1 ;total }
# => {"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>1, "f"=>1
h2 = arr2.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |total, e| total[e] += 1 ;total }
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}

h1.map { |k, v| [k] * [v - h2[k], 0].max }.flatten
# => ["a", "a", "f"]
h2.map { |k, v| [k] * [v - h1[k], 0].max }.flatten
# => ["b", "d"]
```

Comment: `h1` could also be written as `Hash[arr1.map { |v| [v, arr1.count(v)] }]`

Answer (score 0):

When allowing duplicates, Ruby's regular Array arithmetic is pretty much useless.
Try removing elements individually:

```
# Original example
arr1 = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'f']
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd']

# Removing elements from arr1 that exist in arr2 ("arr1 - arr2")
arr1wo2 = arr1.dup
arr2.each { |val| arr1wo2.delete_at(arr1wo2.index(val) || arr1wo2.length) }
arr1wo2  # => ["a", "a", "f"]

# Removing elements from arr2 that exist in arr1 ("arr2 - arr1")
arr2wo1 = arr2.dup
arr1.each { |val| arr2wo1.delete_at(arr2wo1.index(val) || arr2wo1.length) }
arr2wo1  # => ["b", "d"]
```

I hope you find that helpful.